# Slide show in dual monitor system?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, microsoft-powerpoint, slideshow

I have heard about using dual monitors in PC so that you can work smoothly. I would like to use it in a function where I will be connecting a projector to a Windows laptop (Win 7 or later) and show a presentation.

Is it possible to show the slideshow in the projector screen and work with the PC in the laptop screen? I have learned about the presenter mode in MS Office, it shows the slideshow in the projector and speaker notes in the other display, but I do not want the presenter notes instead I work in the other monitor, it it possible to minimise (or avoid) the speaker notes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the Slide Show tab > Show On: > select the screen you want.

[image: powerpoint 2010 second screen settings]

[image: powerpoint second screen settings]

You can even select 'Use Presenter View' to have a different view on the remaining screen, like narrating time, next slide, or select slides randomly. While presenting on the second screen, you can do anything you want on the remaining screen.

Comment: One more doubt, is this option available in Office 2007?

Comment: Don't you see the office 2007 screenshot above? It appears even in office 2003 and prior, of course not in a ribbon

Comment: I couldn't makeout what the version is from the image. Anyway, I hope that it will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is completely possible. If you just present your slideshow full screen on one screen you should be able to use the other screen for whatever you need. You are able to just minimize the speaker notes and continue to work.

Answer (score 0):

When you attach your projector, it will appear as an additional display ("monitor") on your PC.  For Windows 7, do the following.  It is very similar in Windows 8.

1. Open the Control Panel, click Appearance and Personalization, click
   Personalization, and then click Display Settings.
2. To designate the primary display, on the Monitor tab, click the icon
   that corresponds to the monitor that you want to designate as the
   primary display, and then select the This is my main monitor check
   box.
3. Select the screen resolution and color quality for each monitor that
   you're using.

Now that both displays are active, simply move your Powerpoint window to the projector and you can project your presentation while doing anything else you want on the laptop screen.

Comment: Which means, if I fit the powerpoint window in one of the displays and start the slideshow, it will be limited to that monitor only, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  The Powerpoint "slideshow" will by default appear in the display the Powerpoint program is running on.  You can also choose which display the slides will show on from within Powerpoint, but since you said you want to use the laptop display for other programs, just moving Powerpoint to the projector display and then running the slide show is simpler.

Comment: simply move the PowerPoint window doesn't work, because it'll always show on primary monitor by default, as you can see in the above screenshot